How to manage cascading delete behavior for custom objects with complex relationships in Salesforce?
In our Salesforce org, we have several custom objects with parent-child relationships, some of which are deeply nested (e.g., Object A → Object B → Object C). When we delete a record in the top-level object, we want to ensure that all related child records are either deleted or handled according to specific business rules.
Challenges:

Avoiding Orphan Records: We want to prevent any orphan records from remaining after a delete operation on a parent record.
Custom Business Rules: Some child records should be deleted with the parent, while others should be transferred or archived instead.
Performance Concerns: Given the complexity of our relationships, we’re cautious about performance impacts, especially with large data volumes.

Questions:

What are the best practices for implementing cascading delete functionality for custom objects with complex relationships?
Should we use Apex triggers for this logic, or is there a more efficient way to handle cascading deletions?
Are there any Salesforce tools or configurations that can help manage complex delete operations while preserving data integrity?

Looking for practical approaches and any limitations to consider. Thanks!

Managing cascading delete behavior in Salesforce, especially for custom objects with complex relationships, requires careful consideration of both business logic and performance. Below are best practices and approaches to handle cascading deletes effectively:
1. Use Declarative Tools (Where Possible)

Master-Detail Relationships: If your objects have a Master-Detail relationship, Salesforce automatically handles cascading deletes. When a parent record is deleted, all related child records are deleted without any additional coding.
Lookup Relationships: If the relationship is a Lookup (not Master-Detail), cascading deletes are not automatic. In this case, you’ll need to use triggers or other methods to enforce the cascading behavior.

2. Apex Triggers for Custom Logic
If your relationships involve Lookup relationships or you need custom business rules (like transferring or archiving child records instead of deleting them), you’ll need to use Apex triggers. Here’s how you can approach it:

Before Delete Trigger: This trigger fires before a record is deleted, allowing you to check relationships and decide what to do with child records.
After Delete Trigger: If your logic needs to be performed after the parent record is deleted, you can handle it in an "after delete" trigger.

Example of Cascading Logic in a Trigger:
trigger CascadeDelete on ParentObject__c (before delete) {
    List<ChildObject__c> childrenToDelete = new List<ChildObject__c>();
    for (ParentObject__c parent : Trigger.old) {
        // Get related children
        List<ChildObject__c> children = [SELECT Id FROM ChildObject__c WHERE Parent__c = :parent.Id];
        childrenToDelete.addAll(children);
    }
    
    // Delete related children
    delete childrenToDelete;
}

In the example above, you delete child records whenever a parent is deleted. You can add more complex logic to handle specific business rules (e.g., not deleting certain records but updating them or archiving them).
3. Avoid Recursive Deletion
Be cautious of recursive triggers when deleting records. For example, if a child record has a reference to the parent, and you're trying to delete both at the same time, you might run into recursive delete issues. You can use a static variable to prevent recursion.
public class PreventRecursiveDelete {
    public static Boolean isDeleted = false;
}

trigger CascadeDelete on ParentObject__c (before delete) {
    if (PreventRecursiveDelete.isDeleted) {
        return;
    }
    PreventRecursiveDelete.isDeleted = true;
    
    // Your cascading delete logic here
}

4. Data Integrity with Custom Business Rules
If your business logic requires that child records not be deleted but rather archived or transferred, you can modify your trigger logic accordingly. For example:

Archive Instead of Delete: You can create an "Archive" field and update the child record’s status to "Archived" instead of deleting it.
Transfer Records: If a child record needs to be transferred to another parent, you can update its Parent__c field before deletion.

Example:
trigger CascadeDelete on ParentObject__c (before delete) {
    List<ChildObject__c> childrenToUpdate = new List<ChildObject__c>();
    for (ParentObject__c parent : Trigger.old) {
        // Find children to archive or transfer
        List<ChildObject__c> children = [SELECT Id, Parent__c FROM ChildObject__c WHERE Parent__c = :parent.Id];
        for (ChildObject__c child : children) {
            child.Parent__c = 'New Parent Id';  // Transfer child to new parent
            child.Status__c = 'Archived';  // Archive child instead of deleting
            childrenToUpdate.add(child);
        }
    }
    update childrenToUpdate;
}

5. Consider Bulkification
Salesforce limits the number of records that can be processed in a single transaction (e.g., 50,000 records). When handling large data volumes, ensure your logic is bulkified:

Use collections (e.g., List, Set) to process records in bulk rather than iterating over individual records.
Always avoid DML (insert, update, delete) operations within loops.

Example:
trigger CascadeDelete on ParentObject__c (before delete) {
    List<ChildObject__c> childrenToDelete = new List<ChildObject__c>();
    for (ParentObject__c parent : Trigger.old) {
        List<ChildObject__c> children = [SELECT Id FROM ChildObject__c WHERE Parent__c = :parent.Id];
        childrenToDelete.addAll(children);
    }
    delete childrenToDelete;
}

6. Handling Performance Concerns

Use Batch Apex: If you're dealing with a large number of records, consider using Batch Apex to process records in smaller, manageable chunks. This helps avoid hitting governor limits.
Platform Cache: For frequently accessed data (like metadata about which child records should be deleted or archived), consider using Platform Cache to reduce repetitive database queries.

7. Alternative: Declarative Approach with Flow
If the cascading delete requirements are relatively simple and can be handled without complex logic, you might want to consider using Flow (Salesforce’s low-code tool). Flows can be used to delete related child records or update them based on conditions, with a declarative interface, and might reduce the need for writing custom Apex code.

Conclusion:

For Master-Detail relationships, cascading deletes are handled automatically by Salesforce.
For Lookup relationships, use Apex triggers to manage cascading deletes or custom actions like archiving or transferring records.
Performance can be improved with bulkification, Batch Apex, and Platform Cache.
Consider Flow for simpler scenarios to avoid custom code.

With the right design and consideration of your org's complexity, cascading deletes can be managed efficiently in Salesforce.
